# Monogame running very slow on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, monogame

Recently, I decided to resurrect one of my old XNA game projects and port it to a Windows Universal App using Monogame. I managed to get the game running perfectly (albeit with a little less performance) on Windows 8.1, but ran into some huge problems with Windows Phone.

First, it was rendering portrait, but I fixed that using a `RenderTarget2D` as outlined elsewhere. But the most important problem is the <8 fps that the game is running at. I thought it might be a memory problem so I ran the profiler but found nothing out of the ordinary (the game always used about 150MB).

After looking at the output window, I saw that `mscorlib.dll` was throwing about five `System.IO.FileNotFoundExceptions` every second! I knew it was wrong but I couldn't find any additional information on what was happening. It must be something with Monogame because I changed almost no code during the port.

Any ideas?

#### Output (post-build)

```
Other load calls here...

'Operation Furball.WindowsPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.LINQ.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Operation Furball.WindowsPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.CORE.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Operation Furball.WindowsPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\be3bbc51-434b-4ead-9cac-b80c7890a503VS.Debug_AnyCPU.Ramsay\SharpDX.MediaFoundation.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

...many more errors here...

A first chance exception of type '<unknown>' occurred in Unknown Module.
The program '[2896] Operation Furball.WindowsPhone.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: the debug output is _very slow_, your game might run fine without the debugger attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to thumbmunkeys, the problem is fixed. The debugger makes the game very slow, so not attaching the debugger brings the game back to 30fps.

This can be tested by deploying the app using Visual Studio, then stopping the debugger and starting the game on the device.

Comment: You should be able to deploy the game on release mode, which takes the debugger portion out of it automatically :)